# Analytic Extension of $(z-1)\zeta(z)$ to $\{ z: \Re(z) > 0 \}$

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

Let $\zeta(z)$ be the Riemann Zeta Function. I have shown that $\zeta(z)$ is analytic on $\{ \Re(z) > 1 \}$ and established the following equation for $x > 0$

\begin{equation}
\zeta(z) - \int_{1}^\infty x^{-z} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{n}^{n+1}\int_{n}^{x} zt^{-z-1} dtdx
\end{equation}

I have to use this equation to show that $(z-1)\zeta(z)$ has a unique analytic continuation to $\{ \Re(z) >0 \}$.

I realize that there may be other ways to do this, but how can I do this using the equation above. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One help is to look at the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437883/what-is-the-analytic-continuation-of-the-riemann-zeta-function), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2310710/why-can-we-extend-the-zeta-function-from-res-1-to-res-0) and the related links.

Comment: What do you need help for exactly ? Replace $\int_1^\infty x^{-z}dx$ by $1/(z-1)$ and you have your analytic continuation: For $\Re(z) > 1$, $\zeta(z)-1/(z-1)=F(z)$ where $F(z)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{n}^{n+1}\int_{n}^{x} zt^{-z-1} dtdx$ converges and is analytic for $\Re(z) > 0$. (repeating the same method gives the analytic continuation to $\Re(z) > -K$, and it is quite the same as the approach using Bernouilli polynomials)

Comment: Also compare with the analytic continuation of $\sum_{k\ge 0}z^k=1/(1-z)$ to see what's happening

Comment: @reuns Why can you replace $\int_1^\infty x^{-z} dx$ with $1/(z-1)$? Also, How do you know the series converges for $\Re(z) > 0$

Comment: For $\Re(z) > 1$, $\int_1^\infty x^{-z} dx=x^{1-z}/(1-z)|_1^\infty=1/(z-1)$. It is immediate that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{n}^{n+1}\int_{n}^{x}| zt^{-z-1}| dtdx$ converges for $\Re(s) > 0$ for the same reason that $\sum_n n^{-s}$ converges for $s > 1$. The proof that it is analytic is the same as for $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: Why is it immediate? I don't see it

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough rep to comment on the main thread - but as for why $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{n}^{n+1}\int_{n}^{x} zt^{-z-1} dtdx $ converges,

$$ 
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{n}^{n+1}\int_{n}^{x} | zt^{-z-1} | dtdx = 
|z| \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{n}^{n+1}\int_{n}^{x} t^{-z_r-1} dtdx $$ $$< 
|z| \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{n}^{n+1}\int_{n}^{n+1} t^{-z_r-1} dtdx = 
|z| \int_{1}^{\infty} t^{-z_r-1} dt = \frac{|z|}{z_r}
$$

where $z_r$ is the real part of $z$